# If $B \subset C \subset B_g$, is $\mathrm{Spec} C \to \mathrm{Spec} B$ necessarily an open immersion?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $B \subset C$ be Noetherian integral domains, and $g \in B$.  Thus, $\mathrm{Spec} B \to \mathrm{Spec} B_g$ is an open immersion.

If furthermore $C \subset B_g$, does it follow that $\mathrm{Spec} C \to \mathrm{Spec} B$ is an open immersion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. $B=k[x,y]$, $g=x$, $C=k[x, x^{-1} y]$.

Comment: After a few computations, Spec C -> Spec B appears to be the blowing-down morphism in disguise.  Is this correct?

Comment: One of the two charts of it, yes.